# Path For XMl File in Java

Tags: java, file, path

I don't normally post on these sites as usually you find find what you're looking for somewhere on the net. however, after reading every single word of the documentation and reading about a million web pages this is my last hope.

it's something really simple, i'm trying to parse an xml document from a file in my project but no matter what path i use i keep getting a file does not exist error. i have tried EVERY single possible path i can think of. i know i'm making a simple mistake but i just can't figure it out.

here's the start of my code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("/fixtures.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

i've tried putting the `/fixtures.xml` file in the assets folder, the src folder and changing the path accordingly but nothing seems to work.

///////////
i've now moved on trying to access the xml file remotely but this isn't working either. i am using code from tutorials that should obviously work. i can see the file in my local directory and the xml file been uploaded ok so does anyone know what might be going wrong. is there a setting in my project that needs to be changed??

this is the code i'm using to get the xml from the web. you can check the url to see that's it's pointing to the right place.

```
try {
URL url = new URL(
"http://www.spursart.com/fixtures.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
}
catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
```

Comment: @ Elliott Walsh : welcome to SO.  It is okay to ask duplicate questions. You can close/delete if that gets too many downvotes

Comment: what is your platform? Windows or UNIX like?

Comment: @ Elliott Walsh : Your question needs more details. What is assets , src etc?  It seems you  trying to ship a file as web resource.

Comment: @ElliottWalsh can you show us your directory structure, also can you show us the output of `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());` ?

Comment: I really don't think this is a code issue, since I've tested the same code and it works perfect for both cases: local file and remote file. Are you using a Linux O.S or Windows O.S? In case of Linux, please check that you have assigned the rights or permissions to your folders. Can you point the exception you get when tring to get the file from remote location please?

Answer (score 0):

```
File fXmlFile = new File("/fixtures.xml");
```

The starting "/" means a file at the root of file system.  It is almost not possible to have this file.  Windows typically will have drive names and unix you have to be root (admin) to have this there

The following will use file in the current working directory.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("fixtures.xml");
```

Comment: i've tried that. i've tried every possible path name i can think of.

Comment: i've tried things like "res/layout/fixtures.xml", "assets/xml/fixtures.xml". i know i'm doing something really stupid but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your xml file path by below method.. so that you can your code.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("xxx.txt"); 
//or File fXmlFile = new File("/xxx.txt"); 
System.out.println("Path=" +fXmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: i've already tried that as well! Path=/fixtures.xml, but when i try "fixtures.xml" as the path i get a file does not exist error :/

Comment: Try with empty file.. so that atleast you can know what is the default path it is refering  :                                                 File fXmlFile = new File("");
System.out.println("Path=" +fXmlFile.getAbsolutePath());